# How do I fix this Heroku client tools error: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen?

Tags: heroku

I'm brand new to Heroku.  I'm following the instructions on this [Salesforce Mobile Services tutorial](https://developer.salesforce.com/mobile/getting-started/html5#angularjs).  I've followed the instructions, but when I try to run this command: `heroku login` I get the following error:

> C:\MobileTest\MobilePack-AngularJS\samples\AngularHerokuBootstrapNode>heroku -version
>   heroku-cli: Installing Toolbelt v4... done
>   For more information on Toolbelt v4: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-cli
>    !    Heroku client internal error.
>    !    Search for help at: https://help.heroku.com
>    !    Or report a bug at: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/new 
>   Error:       Permission denied - "C:\Users\Rodney\AppData\Local/heroku/herok
>   u-cli.exe" version (Errno::EACCES)
>       Command:     heroku -version
>       Version:     heroku/toolbelt/3.42.45 (i386-mingw32) ruby/2.1.7
>       Error ID:    b6c04898fb3143d48f140c60feded0d7
>       More information in C:/Users/Rodney/.heroku/error.log

Here's what the referenced log says:

> Heroku client internal error.
>   Permission denied - "C:\Users\Rodney\AppData\Local/heroku/heroku-cli.exe" version
>   C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/jsplugin.rb:108:in ``'
>   C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/jsplugin.rb:108:in `version'
>   C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/jsplugin.rb:149:in`setup'
>   C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/cli.rb:27:in `start'
>   C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/bin/heroku:29:in`'
>   Heroku client internal error.
>   Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - C:\Users\Rodney\AppData\Local/heroku/heroku-cli.exe
>   C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/2.1.0/digest.rb:46:in `initialize'
>   C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/2.1.0/digest.rb:46:in`open'
>   C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/2.1.0/digest.rb:46:in `file'
>   C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/2.1.0/digest.rb:31:in`file'
>   C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/jsplugin.rb:144:in `setup'
>   C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/cli.rb:27:in`start'
>   C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/bin/heroku:29:in `'

Upon first installation of Heroku client toolbelt, I didn't install as admin.  I've since uninstalled Heroku client toolbelt and reinstalled as administrator.  No luck.

Answer (score 1):

After much trial and error and then Googling, it seems others were having the problem as noted here on [github/heroku](https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20%20Error%3A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Permission%20denied%20%40%20rb_sysopen)

The problem was my antivirus was falsly sending the heroku-cli.exe file to quarantine.  That file is needed when running a `heroku` command.

I went into my antivirus (Vipre) and restored the heroku-cli.exe file to always allow.  Now I can run `heroku` commands without error.

I hope that helps someone else out who searches StackExchange first like I did.